# parallelize a time-consuming Python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have a nested for loop that is time-consuming. I think parallelization can make it faster, but I do not know how I use it. this is my for loop in my code :

```
for itr2 in range(K):
            tmp_cl=clusters[itr2+1]
            if len(tmp_cl)>1:
                BD_cent=np.zeros((len(tmp_cl),1))
                for itr3 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                    sumv=0
                    for itr5 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                        condition = psnr_bitrate == tmp_cl[itr3,:]
                        where_result = np.where(condition)
                        tidx1 = where_result[0]
                        condition = psnr_bitrate == tmp_cl[itr5,:]
                        where_result = np.where(condition)
                        tidx2 = where_result[0]
                        BD_R=bd_rate(rate[tidx1[0],:],tmp_cl[itr3,:],rate[tidx2[0],:],tmp_cl[itr5,:])
                        BD_R=(BD_R-min_BDR)/(max_BDR-min_BDR)
                        BD_Q=bd_PSNR(rate[tidx1[0],:],tmp_cl[itr3,:],rate[tidx2[0],:],tmp_cl[itr5,:])
                        BD_Q=(BD_Q-min_BDQ)/(max_BDQ-min_BDQ)
                        value=(wr*BD_R+wq*BD_Q)
                        if value!=np.NINF:
                            sumv+=(value)
                        else:
                            sumv+=1000#for the curve which has not overlap with others
                    BD_cent[itr3]=sumv/len(tmp_cl)
                
                new_centroid_index=np.argmin(BD_cent)
                centroid[itr2]=clusters[itr2+1][new_centroid_index]
```

I checked some other examples about parallelization in Stackoverflow, but as a beginner, I could not understand what is the solution. do I have to define a function for code in the for loops? this for loops compute the distance between every two points in K=6 different clusters. but for parallelization, I do not know how do I use `asyncio` or `joblib`. is it possible for these loops or not?

Answer (score 0):

CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) or [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor).